# What are all of the classified codes for Halo Waypoint

Tags: halo-4, halo-anniversary, halo-series, halo-waypoint

What are the classified codes for Halo Waypoint, what does each unlock, and where can the codes be obtained?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[You can go here to enter these codes on your computer (much faster this way).](http://www.halowaypoint.com/en-us/classified)

The terminal code entry page can be translated into A-Z and 0-9 according to this chart.

[image: Terminal Alphabet Guide]

You'll notice the symbol in the middle doesn't have a glyph. Many others translate it to be Æ but that is harder to read in a code, so I will be using #. Below is a list of all known codes to date. The format is "CODE - Unlocks - Obtained from".

## Current Codes

### Halo Anniversary

- 343GS - Terminal Video + 7000cr (Reach) - Halo: Anniversary Terminal Video
- HALO4 - Terminal Video + 7000cr (Reach) - Halo: Anniversary Terminal Video
- SPARK - Terminal Video + 7000cr (Reach) - Halo: Anniversary Terminal Video
- FLOOD - Terminal Video + 7000cr (Reach) - Halo: Anniversary Terminal Video
- EARTH - Terminal Video + 7000cr (Reach) - Halo: Anniversary Terminal Video
- DEMON - Terminal Video + 7000cr (Reach) - Halo: Anniversary Terminal Video
- RINGS - Terminal Video + 7000cr (Reach) - Halo: Anniversary Terminal Video
- ARRAY - Terminal Video + 7000cr (Reach) - Halo: Anniversary Terminal Video
- HUMAN - Terminal Video + 7000cr (Reach) - Halo: Anniversary Terminal Video
- HAVEN - 2 Terminal Videos + 7000cr (Reach) - Halo: Anniversary Terminal Video

### Halo 4

#### Requiem Archive 1

- **1UK3CVYJZM** - Raider Torso Armor + 500xp (Halo 4) - **REQUIRED :** Complete "Sniper Alley" in Spartan Ops and [get code from here](http://www.halowaypoint.com/en-us/universe/tag/143).
- **3VGRZJ1BS6** - Raider Shoulder Armor + 500xp (Halo 4) - **REQUIRED :** Complete "Land Grab" in Spartan Ops and [get code from here](http://www.halowaypoint.com/en-us/universe/tag/143).
- **Q239SF2PGZ** - Raider Helmet + 500xp (Halo 4) - **REQUIRED :** Complete "The Challenge" in Spartan Ops and [get code from here](http://www.halowaypoint.com/en-us/universe/tag/143).

*Note: Unlocking Raider Helmet, shoulder, and torso unlocks concept art, 500xp, and the Raider emblem.

#### Requiem Archive 2

- **MN7VKCZP#Q** - Raider "DSTT" Shoulders - **REQUIRED :** Complete 15 chapters of Spec Ops on Legendary
- **WQ6F2Y1M1P** - Raider "DSTT" Torso - **REQUIRED :** Complete Campaign on Legendary (solo or co-op)
- **8PXX1SMIQU** - Raider "DSTT" Helment - **REQUIRED :** Play 1000 War Games (Multiplayer)

#### Section 3 Archive

- **T5CE6KV3R8** - 5000xp (Halo 4) + ONI Emblem + Concept Art - **REQUIRED :** First Data Terminal in Campaign Mission "Requiem" unlocked
- **9WE621KN8F** - 2000xp (Halo 4) + Wiseguy Emblem + Concept Art - **REQUIRED :** All data terminals unlocked
- **M0DKE#EMQC** - Recruit Emblem + 12116xp (Halo 4) - Most likely required to have played at some point on or before 11/8/12. (If it doesn't work on the website, try it on your Xbox 360, and vice versa.)
- **1K3G7N17LL** - "Curious" Article + 20000xp (Halo 4) - No known requirements
- **EBGROIVIDR** - LASO Emblem + 50000xp - **REQUIRED :** Complete the game on Legendary with All Skulls On. Coop or Solo. Mixed reports on Blind being on, but I'd recommend it on.
- **GT#RFIEU6Q** - Majestic Concept Art + 25000xp (Halo 4) - No Known Requirements

### New Codes

New codes are being release through [an ARG](https://forums.halowaypoint.com/yaf_profile359186.aspx). [A forum post](https://forums.halowaypoint.com/yaf_postst121232_Decrypting-Section-3---UPDATE-11-05.aspx) is used to track current progress and points to [a Wix site meant for collective decoding of clues](http://mingcool2000.wix.com/section3-decryption#!current-leads/c21e0). On the site you can find a [full list of current codes](http://mingcool2000.wix.com/section3-decryption#!completed-codes/c1dsn) as well as [a list of codes in progress](http://mingcool2000.wix.com/section3-decryption#!copy-of-blank/c1o07). Join in to help find more codes.

Comment: The day 1 , people from the 1st day to 8th of November, it also gives out 12,116 xp

Comment: Yeah, the day 1 code only works on www.halowaypoint.com not the console version of waypoint